# what can I do with an old corny keg?

Tags: keg, corny-keg

I have a corny keg with a neck that doesnt seal what else can i do with it besides carb. and serve beer? above the seal it is all bent up and have tied to repair with no success.

Comment: This should be a wiki as there is no definitive answer.  Its a better forum/discussion topic that a question with an answer.

Comment: how do i do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small batch fermentor.
Sanitizer holder for long items like racking canes, spoons and tubing.